# kafka-streams - are TopologyBuilder/KStreamBuilder objects reusable?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

Are `org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.TopologyBuilder`/`org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.KStreamBuilder` objects reusable?

I want to provide ability to re-start the given kafka streaming application with precisely the same config.

So far the following code has been working, but I have not found any hard confirmation in documentation:

```
TopologyBuilder topology = ...
Properties properties = ...

// first time
KafkaStreams handle1 = new KafkaStreams(topology, properties);
handle1.start()
...
handle1.stop()

// second time
KafkaStreams handle2 = new KafkaStreams(topology, properties); // <- is this safe?
handle2.start()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they are reusable and what you are doing is absolutely safe.